# Linux: attach a script to controlling terminal after setsid

Tags: linux, bash, setsid

If I run a Bash script via the `setsid` command, its controlling terminal will not be attached to any device (it will show up as "?"). 
Is there a way to re-attach the controlling terminal to some free `pts` device from a shell script.

Will I be able to use `stdin` and `stdout` inside the script run via `setsid`, after its controlling terminal gets detached?

Comment: There is no *easy* way AFAIK. Take a look [here](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/02/changing-ctty/)

Comment: maybe this? https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr

Comment: Of course you can use stdin and stdout.  But I think you intend to ask "can I make the stdin of the script be associated with my keyboard, and the stdout be associated with a tty?"

Comment: @WilliamPursell - yes, that is exactly what I mean. Isn't that going to be the case that after starting the new session, stdin and stdout will still be working on the current terminal, I just won't be able to send the control signals? What I am looking for is a way to run commands in a separate sessions so that they can easily be all terminated; but at the same time, I wouldn't like to change the way these commands are run by, e.g. disabling stdin keyboard access.

Comment: You can send a signal to every process in the group using kill.  From the man page: ` Negative PID values may  be  used  to  choose  whole process groups`.  If you want to be able to do that with ctrl-C, keep your shell script in the foreground, run everything else in a setsid'd subshell and trap SIGTERM to send the signal to the group.